# Randomly choosing from an array without repetitions

Tags: arrays, random, lua

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how I would go about choosing a phrase from an array randomly, without having multiple phrases appear twice in a row. For example, if I had this list of phrases:

```
phraseList = {"pig","cow","cat","dog","horse","mouse","giraffe"}
```

I would pick from them randomly using this:

```
startPhrase = phraseList[math.random(#phraseList)]
```

But if I ran that line multiple times, how would I make different phrases appear every time, until it runs out of phrases, while it still being randomized? Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start with a copy of the original list, and then each time you randomly pick an element, remove it from that list. The count will automatically decrease, so your next pick will again be evenly spread over the remaining items. Then when the list runs out, start again with a fresh copy of the original list.

Here is a possible script:

```
local phraseList = {"pig","cow","cat","dog","horse","mouse","giraffe"}
local copyPhraseList = {}

function pickPhrase()
    local i
    -- make a copy of the original table if we ran out of phrases
    if #copyPhraseList == 0 then
        for k,v in pairs(phraseList) do
            copyPhraseList[k] = v
        end
    end

    -- pick a random element from the copy  
    i = math.random(#copyPhraseList)
    phrase = copyPhraseList[i] 

    -- remove phrase from copy
    table.remove(copyPhraseList, i)

    return phrase
end

-- call it as many times as you need it:
print (pickPhrase())
print (pickPhrase())
```

Comment: How would I make the list restart when the phrases run out? I want to pick a phrase more times than the amount of phrases in the list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But then you will have duplicates? Wasn't that your restriction? You first want to empty the list and only then have duplicates?

Comment: I don't want the phrases to be repeated unless they have to be. So once the list runs out, yes, there would have the be duplicates. I pretty much just don't want the same phrase to be repeated twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Lua but I think the following should be possible in Lua.

How about introducing a new array whose elements represent indexes of phraseList: idx = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Then randomly arrange the elements of idx. Finally, use the elements of idx in sequence to choose the elements of phraseList? - john